# How to make git buildpackage use bash instead of sh

Tags: linux, git, bash, shell

I am using git buildpackage to create debian packages from my application.

In the Debian folder under my application directory I have a gbp.conf file overriding the defaults for gbp:

```
[DEFAULT]
builder = dpkg-buildpackage -b
ignore-new = True
prebuild = if [[ $(sed -n 's|^[ ]*foobarVersion = "\(.*\)"|\1|p' example.file) == *"TEST"* ]]; then echo "yes"; fi
```

The prebuild command works fine when I put it in a .sh file with a shebang #!/bin/bash at the top and also works straigt in command line. But it looks like git buildpackage runs the command with bin/sh because I get the following error:

```
me@my-instance:~/application$ git buildpackage
/bin/sh: 1: [[: not found
```

How can I make git buildpackage use bin/bash instead of bin/sh when calling prebuild commands from gbp.conf?
If it's a simpler solution, how would I write the following statement to work with bin/sh?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I’ve never used git buildpackage but you should be able to replace the `[[` Bash-specific shell builtin with the POSIX `case` command in order to match against a pattern; `sh` is the POSIX compliant shell implementation.

Instead of

```
if [[ $(sed -n 's|^[ ]*foobarVersion = "\(.*\)"|\1|p' example.file) == *"TEST"* ]]; then echo "yes"; fi
```

use

```
case "$(sed -n 's|^[ ]*foobarVersion = "\(.*\)"|\1|p' example.file)" in *TEST*) echo yes; esac
```